# Ping servers and execute command when all respond

Tags: bash, ping

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

servers=( "10.10.10.1" "10.10.10.2" "10.10.10.3" "10.10.10.4" )

for i in "${servers[@]}";
do
ping -c 4 "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
echo "Ping Status of $i : Success" ||
echo "Ping Status of $i : Failed"
done
```

which outputs

```
Ping Status of 10.10.10.1 : Success
Ping Status of 10.10.10.2 : Success
Ping Status of 10.10.10.3 : Failed
Ping Status of 10.10.10.4 : Failed
```

I need to constantly ping those addresses until they all succeed then, execute a command. I don't need the success/failed output, I just want to ping all IPs and then echo "All Hosts Online", for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the comments in the code make it clear what this does. Basically, the trick is to wrap the entire thing in an infinite `while` loop, and use a variable to signal whether one of the commands failed.

```
#!/bin/bash

servers=( "10.10.10.1" "10.10.10.2" "10.10.10.3" "10.10.10.4" )

# Keep looping forever : is a special builtin command that does
# nothing and always exits with code 0
while :; do
    # Assume success
    failed=0

    # Loop over all the servers
    for i in "${servers[@]}"; do
        # We failed one!
        if ! ping -c 4 "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            # Set failed to 1 to signal the code after the for loop that
            # a ping failed
            failed=1

             # We don't need to ping the others, so we can break from this for
             # loop
             break
        fi
    done

    # If none of the ping commands failed, the $failed variable is still 0
    if [ $failed -eq 0 ]; then
        # Yes! We can now run our command
        echo "All hosts online"

        # And break the infinite while loop
        break
    else
        # Nope, wait a while and start the loop from the top
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```

I also fixed a typo; you used `/dev/nul`, but that should be `/dev/null`, with two `l`.

Comment: that's excellent thanks, is there also a way to change from infinite to x minutes?

Comment: @Lurch You mean you want it to stop after *n* minutes if not all of the servers can be reached? Sure, just add `start=$(date +%s)` at the top, and then inside the script check `if [ $(date +%s) -gt $(( $start + SECONDS )) ]; then break; fi` (fill in SECONDS to what you want).

Comment: Wxcellent thanks, ah missed null typo, fat fingers moment.